# JavaFX PrinterJob adding margin while printing, pushing it off of page

Tags: java, javafx

I have all of my information in a VBox, so I am trying to print it, but it keeps adding a HUGE margin and pushing half of the VBox off my screen. I have tried passing it as a node, making the margin 0, disabling ALL the padding in my Main.java, but nothing has worked. I am printing as PDF, so I don't believe my printer is the issue. Any help would be greatly helped! (Also, I am fairly new, so please don't roast me

```
public class PrintStructure {

public void print(final VBox node)
{

    try
    {
        // Select printer
        final PrinterJob job = Objects.requireNonNull(PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(), "Cannot create printer job");
        final Scene scene = Objects.requireNonNull(node.getScene(), "Missing Scene");

        if (! job.showPrintDialog(scene.getWindow()))
            return;

        // Scale image to full page

        final Printer printer = job.getPrinter();
        final Paper paper = job.getJobSettings().getPageLayout().getPaper();
        final PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(paper,
                PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
        final double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getWidth();
        final double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getHeight();
        final Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, scaleY);
        node.getTransforms().add(scale);

        if (job != null) {
            boolean success = job.printPage(node);
            if (success) {
                System.out.println("Done printing!");
                job.endJob();
                node.getTransforms().remove(scale);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure the print shows the settings before printing. That way you can print to pdf and save paper. It will also allow you to play with the print settings. Maybe you can get some clue of what's going wrong using those. It will also allow you to play with the print settings in your code without wasting paper.

Comment: @Sedrick Yes I am printing to PDF which is why I don't think its an issue with my printer